# Does Swype Beta collects typed passwords?

Tags: swype

Their [FAQ](http://beta.swype.com/android/faq/) doesn't mention this, but when I enable Swype on my Galaxy S2, I get a notification warning me that it can collect all info, including credit card numbers and passwords.

Does it collect such data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a standard Android warning. You get that warning when you try to install any keyboard.

Nope, it won't collect any such data.

Comment: How do you know it won't?